# How to use the react-hook-form package in conjunction with zod and my schema?

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I want to achieve the functionality where the user first enters the email, and after the email has been validated and the user clicks on the *Continue with email* button, then a verification code is sent to the backend and the input to enter the code appears (this should appear only when the email has been validated and the user clicks on the *Continue with email* button), and after entering the code the user should be able to click on the *Sign in* button. The *Sign in* button will also be displayed only when the input to enter the code is displayed, and when the *Sign in* button is displayed, the *Continue with email* button should not be displayed.

I can achieve this with React, but I wanted to achieve this using `react-hook-form` in conjuction with `zod` and my schema.

Here is what I have till now, can someone please help me with this?

```
function SignUp() {
  const [isCodeSent, setIsCodeSent] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(AuthenticationSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(errors);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-screen gap-14">
      <h2 className="text-4xl font-semibold">Sign Up</h2>
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-10">
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="w-[300px] flex gap-3 flex-col"
        >
          <div>
            <label className="text-sm text-label" htmlFor="email">
              Email
            </label>
            <div className="flex items-center w-full gap-1 p-2 mt-0.5 rounded-md shadow-inside bg-input-foreground">
              <input
                className="w-full text-base bg-transparent placeholder:text-input-placeholder"
                type="email"
                id="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email address"
                {...register("email")}
              />
              <div className="cursor-pointer">
                <XCircle color={"rgba(55, 53, 47, 0.35)"} size={"20"} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {!isCodeSent && (
            <div>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => isValid && setIsCodeSent(true)}
                className="w-full p-2 font-medium rounded-md shadow-[inset_0_0_0_1px_rgba(235,87,87,0.3)] bg-[rgb(253,245,242)] text-[rgb(235,87,87)]"
              >
                Continue with email
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
          {isCodeSent && (
            <>
              <div>
                <label className="text-sm text-label" htmlFor="signup-code">
                  Code
                </label>
                <div className="flex items-center w-full gap-1 p-2 mt-0.5 rounded-md shadow-inside bg-input-foreground">
                  <input
                    className="w-full text-base bg-transparent placeholder:text-input-placeholder"
                    type="text"
                    id="signup-code"
                    placeholder="Enter sign up code"
                    {...register("code")}
                  />
                  <div className="cursor-pointer">
                    <XCircle color={"rgba(55, 53, 47, 0.35)"} size={"20"} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="w-full p-2 mt-2 font-medium rounded-md shadow-[inset_0_0_0_1px_rgba(235,87,87,0.3)] bg-[rgb(253,245,242)] text-[rgb(235,87,87)]"
                >
                  Create new email
                </button>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </form>
        <div className="w-full py-10 border-t border-t-border">
          <button className="flex items-center justify-center w-full gap-0.5 p-2 rounded-md shadow-inside hover:bg-primary-hover transition">
            <Google />
            Continue with Google
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my schema:

```
export const AuthenticationSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email({ message: "Please enter a valid email address." }),
  code: z
    .string()
    .length(5, { message: "The code should be of 5 characters in length" })
    .optional(),
});
```

If you can suggest a better way to achieve this than the code above, that works too. I just need to use `react-hook-form` and `zod`.